# DotNet Irony Understanding

Tags: c#

[Irony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony_(framework)) includes two phases. In the first phase it create a parser tree. After that its optional to create an AST tree.

What are the differences between the parse tree and the AST tree?

What is the reason to implement that?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Parse Tree*s are also sometimes referred to as *Concrete Syntax Tree*s to distinguish them from *Abstract Syntax Tree*s, which maybe already tells you what they are all about.

Basically, a parse tree is still dependent on the actual concrete syntax used in the source code. E.g. if a language has two ways of defining a function that are semantically equivalent, then the parse tree might still tell you which of the ways was used. The parse tree might also still contain artifacts of the specific parser that was used, e.g. if the parser supports left-recursion or doesn't, etc.

The AST, OTOH, should ideally be independent of any *particular* concrete syntax that was used in the source code and the particular parser that was used. In theory, an AST should be abstract enough that it can even serve as an interface between the parser and the rest of the system, IOW in theory, I should be able to swap in a different parser which generates the same AST without the rest of the system noticing. (In practice, that is seldomly possible, though.)

Comment: If a system distinguishes between parse trees and ASTs, this usually means that the parse tree contains enough data about comments, indentation, and parenthesization that it could be be used to losslessly produce an equivalent source file. This is useful e.g. for code formatters.